# Upload file in Rails 3.2 app - develop engine or use gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload, upload

We are looking to add a simple file uploader to our rails 3.2 app which is a business application (with Rails engines). Here are what we are looking for with the file uploader:

1. Allow access control to who can do what. For example, sales can upload a contract and acct can view the uploaded contract.
2. No change to current model. The file uploader acts on its own about file uploading, checking, storing and removing. We are thinking to have a file uploader engine and attach the engine to the Rails app.
3. File uploaded belongs to a model. For example, uploaded contract copy belongs to a project.
4. May need to upload file to a remote server.

We are evaluating options of developing our own uploader engine or find a upload gem such as `carrierwave` or `paperclip`. Can someone shed a light on rails file uploading and its related issue?

Comment: Rails file uploading and its related issue.

Comment: I have used paperclip with a rails 3.2 app. It is very simple to implement. As far as the allowing access control.. I would use pundit or cancan for that.

Comment: @@fresh5447， can you implement any type of access control with paperclip? we implemented our own action/resource based access control and would like to use it for file uploading as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a combination of cancan  and paperclip is a good option.